# Enable arbitrary sized collections in Boost MPL and Fusion

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Using Boost Fusion and MPL collections, I end up having to add this to the compiler flags:

```
BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS
BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE=50
FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE=50
FUSION_MAX_MAP_SIZE=50
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) with Boost 1.62.

Hasn't support for arbitrary sized collections been added to these libraries by the use of variadic templates?

If so, how can I force boost MPL and Fusion to use the variadic version with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fusion has varadic containers for a quite time, but it was disabled for MSVC because of ICE (Internal Compiler Error). The [patch](https://github.com/boostorg/fusion/pull/146) that re-enables varadic containers for MSVC (VS2015 U3+) was landed in Boost 1.65.

MPL has no varadic support. There were some tries (for example, [mpl11](https://github.com/ldionne/mpl11) by Boost.Hana developer) but no one ended with a PR.